# Website displays extremely small in mobile, properly on resized desktop browser

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm creating a small site just to test out my mobile HTML/CSS skills and I've run into a strange problem. Everything looks EXTREMELY tiny on my mobile device or in Chrome mobile device dev tools, but displays properly in my browser when I resize the width down to 400px or lower. I'm really not sure what is going wrong here as I've built sizes using about these dimensions in the past (11px font size etc) and they displayed properly on all platforms. Really not sure what is up. Anyone have any insight?

Take a look at it right here: http://gfitzpatrickportfolio.com/flights/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this tag in all your pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It will fit the content to the screen, in the correct scales. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Viewport Metatag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to fits the whole content on mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```